# nbconvert failed: pdflatex not found on PATH

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pdflatex

[Pdflatex not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPOYv.png)

I installed MacTex successfully and tried to add path 
     export PATH="/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin:$PATH"
into the ./bash_profile

but still gets the same error in Python Notebook.

Comment: [Resolved] Rebooting the terminal solved my issue.